# Prove that if P(E|F1) = P(E|F2) = P(E|G) for some F1, F2 ⊆ G, then P(E|F1 ∪ F2) = P(E|G).

Tags: probability

Im struggling with proving the following identity any help would be great.

Comment: Consider writing a more extended body for your question instead of putting everything on the title.

Comment: Have you looked for a counterexample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not obviously true.

Consider as a counterexample the following equally probable cases with indicators:

```
E  F1 F2 G Probability 
0  1  0  1    0.2
1  1  0  1    0.1
1  1  1  1    0.1
1  0  1  1    0.1
0  0  1  1    0.2
1  0  0  1    0.1
1  0  0  0    0.1
0  0  0  0    0.1
```

Then $F_1 \subseteq G$ and $F_2 \subseteq G$,

and $\mathbb P(E \mid F_1)=\frac{0.2}{0.4} = \frac12$, $\mathbb P(E \mid F_2)=\frac{0.2}{0.4} = \frac12$,  $\mathbb P(E \mid G)=\frac{0.4}{0.8} = \frac12$,

but $\mathbb P(E \mid F_1 \cup F_2)=\frac{0.3}{0.7} = \frac37 \not = \frac12$

Comment: That s really helpful, thanks a lot!